# Relationship between Potential and Potential energy

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electrostatics, potential, potential-energy

I know that if we have a conservative force then:
$\vec{F}(r)=-\vec{\nabla}V(r)$ where $V(r)$ is the potential.
I also know that I can take potential energy from here doing: $E_{pot} (r) = \int_{S} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}$, where $S$ is just a path.

Ok, but I don't understand what is the relationship between potential and potential energy.

And also: we know that electric potential is given by $V(r)=\frac{k_e Q}{r}$ so we can obtain the force using $\vec{F}(r)=-\vec{\nabla}V(r)$ it comes that $\vec{F}(r)=\frac{k_e Q}{r^2}\hat{r}$ which is wrong by Coulomb's law...what is wrong in my thinking?

Comment: The force is the gradient of potential energy and not of potential. It is quite common to hear (or read) that the a conservative force is derived from "potential" but it is just a shorthand. It should be potential energy.

Comment: @nasu, yes, I read both definitions at the internet but I heard my teachers saying "force is derived from potential" so I thought it was potential. So but if have the function of the potential (not energy!), how do I get the energy?

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): $V(r)$ in OP's first sentence is in fact the potential energy, not the (electric) potential. Consider to add a reference for the claim in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In mechanics, we love energy: indeed, it often really simplifies solving problems. Often, we want to know how the speed of a particle varies, or, in other words, what its kinetic energy is. Luckily, for some forces, knowing the variation in kinetic energy is really easy: these forces are the *conservative* forces. A force $\textbf{F}$ is conservative when its work along a path $\Gamma$ only depends on the initial and final positions: then, we can introduce a *potential energy*, say $E_p$, so that

$$ W(\textbf{F}) = \int_\Gamma \textbf{F}\cdot\textbf{dl} = E_{pi} - E_{pf}$$

However, the kinetic energy theorem states that the total work done on a particle equals its kinetic energy variation, so

$$ \Delta KE = W(\textrm{F}) = -\Delta E_p $$

Now, let's focus on Coulomb's law. Consider a charge $Q$ in $P$, and another one, say $q$ in $M$. It appears that $Q$ creates a force $\textbf{F}_e$ on $q$, with

$$\textbf{F}_e = \frac{Qq}{4\pi\epsilon \|\textbf{PM}\|^3}\textbf{PM}$$

Since $\textbf{F}_e$ only depends on the position of $P$ and $M$, it is derived from a potential energy $E_p$, and we find that

$$ E_p = \frac{Qq}{4\pi\epsilon\|\textbf{PM}\|}$$

However, even if the notation is usefull for a few particles, it really becomes difficul when studying a complex distribution of charges. Then, we prefer to see a single charge as the *source* of an *electric field* $\textbf{E}$, which exists everywhere, with $$\textbf{E}(M) = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon \|\textbf{PM}\|^3}\textbf{PM}$$

Now, multiplying $\textbf{E}$ by the charge $q$ gives the electric force created by $Q$. So, $\textbf{E}$ and $\textbf{F}_e$ are almost the same: we introduce $U$ which is the *potential* created by $Q$, so that $E_p = qU$.

Answer (score 0):

$ - \nabla V$ gives you, in fact. The electric field, not the electric force. In order to obtain electric force you must do $ \vec{F} = q\vec{E} $, and that will eventually lead to coulombs law.
The relation between electric potential and electric energy comes from the charge $q$. For example:
Let $q$ be a charge in an electric field that will follow a trajectory $ C$. We define the work done by the electric field as $ W = qV$, where $V$ is the difference between the initial electric potential and final electric potential (a proof of this formula can be found in any college-level electromagnetism book).
So, roughly, one can say that the electric potential at a point P is the amount of work it takes to move a charge $q$ from infinity to the point P (assuming $ V(\infty) = 0 $). It is something like "amount of work per unity of charge".

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between *potential* $V$ and *potential energy* $U$ is:

$$V= \frac Uq$$

Talking electricity, $q$ is charge. Talking gravity, $q$ would instead be mass $m$. Similar for chemical, magnetic and other types of potentials.

The *potential* is simply *potential energy **per** something*. For example potential energy per unit of charge, or per unit of mass etc.